# Empty array in useEffect vs useCallback in parent for server api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an api call to my server on component mount, so at first I did it with empty array in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
        }
    }).then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => setUserChats(data))              
}
}, [])
```

But there is a warning for dependencies and it says to use callback in parent, but I don't understand what is the differnce in memorizing the method with empty array in the parent vs just empty array in effect:

Parent.js:

```
const setChatsCallback = useCallback(chats => {
    setChats(chats)
  }, [])
```

Child.js:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
        }
    }).then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => setUserChats(data))         
}, [setChatsContainer])
```

Also I have seen places where they first define the method in the useEffect and then call it is there a diffrenece between that and just put the logic in the useEffect directly:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    async function doRequest() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',{
            headers: {
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
            }
        }).then(data => data.json())
          .then(data => setUserChats(data))               
    }
    doRequest()
}, [setChatsContainer])
```

And if there is a differrence can I just do it with self executing function:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    (async() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',{
            headers: {
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
            }
        }).then(data => data.json())
          .then(data => setUserChats(data))

          smoothscroll.polyfill()
          setChatsContainer(chatsContainer)                
    })()
}, [setChatsContainer])
```

Comment: What is the "warning for dependencies" that you're referring to?

Comment: @goto1 it's known warning:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'setChatsContainer' and 'setUserChats'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'setChatsContainer' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: I am a little confused, you're getting that warning from your first code snippet? Are you sure that's all you have? By the way, it wouldn't make sense to put `setChartsContainer` or `setUserCharts` in your dependency array - are you sure that's all there is?

Comment: @goto1 You can google it, there are even stackoverflow question that suggest to do it the second way. It is not releated to anything else in my code

Comment: It wasn't clear that the `setUserCharts` is coming from a parent as a `prop` now that I am reading the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is using `setUserChats` which comes from props. As props can change react assumes your effect should run whenever this callback changes. Thus the warning for missing dependencies.

Defining an async callback inline and calling it in a `useEffect` is required if you want to use the `async/await` syntax instead of `Promise.then()` as the callback given to `useEffect` itself is not allowed to be async. If you are only using `.then()` you do not need it. There is no practical difference between defining an anonymous arrow function and directly calling it and defining a named function and calling it.

Those are both doing the same:

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
        }
    }).then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => setUserChats(data))         
}, [setUserChats])
```

and

```
useEffect(() =>  {
    (async() => {
        const response = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:8080/api/chat/auth/getChats?pageSize=3',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Authorization')
                }
            }
        )

        const data = await response.json()

        setUserChats(data) 
    })()
}, [setUserChats])
```

Some people (myself included) prefer the `async/await` syntax as it is easier to follow the control flow. Note that this is an opinion.

Comment: So there is no optimization or change in behaviour only surpassing the warning?

Comment: @ivaylo Of course there is a change in behaviour. Whenever `setUserChats` changes your effect will run again vs. it will only run once on mount if you leave it out.

Comment: Yes, I mean in scenario where there is no change in setChats method, do both ways work identical?

Comment: @ivaylo Yes, it will make no difference. React just doesn't know that it will never change in your case thus the warning.